# Android Studio export library\SDK without exposing the code

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sdk, android-proguard

I have an Android Studio project in which I build an SDK and export it to Jcenter so that clients will be able to use my SDK in their own project by adding 1 line of "compile.. " to their build.gradle.

So far everything went well but I do have one problem, my clients can see all of the SDK code from their project. I'm trying to understand what will be the best way to hide my implementation without breaking anything. Obviously proguard will probably be involved in the solution, however to my surprise I haven't seen any "best practice" solution to achieve what I want.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, a library on the public jCenter repository provided by **Bintray** is [OSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) (Open Source Sofware).

This is what I've done to protect my code :

**1.** All the code is **obfuscated with Proguard**. There are some rules on very specific classes so the library work correctly.

**2.** My organization have subscribed to the *Professional* plan on Bintray witch allow us to **not have a OSS library**. See [pricing](https://bintray.com/account/pricing?tab=account&type=pricing). Doing this, the developer will need to add your bintray repo and after the dependencies. If you prefer, I guess you could do as Fabric/Twitter to have your own code repositories using maven, and host your library yourself.

**Don't forget that a class file can always be *Decompiled* so you cannot really prevent this.**

**As a personnal note,** If your planning to earn money with your library, maybe think about an OSS library and a prenium server side service like Parse.com where the [client library](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android) is OSS.